# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException no Designer XAML VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Estou com um problema no Visual Studio. Quando eu crio um novo projeto UWP10 em branco, ele vem o o código básico.

```
<Page
    x:Class="FoxMovieStoreMain.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FoxMovieStoreMain"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

E o designer mostra o preview da Page normalmente. Porém ao substituir o código XAML por esse:

```
<Page x:Name="AppMainPage"
    x:Class="FoxMovieStoreMain.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FoxMovieStoreMain"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="GridToMainPage">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="RelatMainPanelTop" Background="#FFFF6800">

            <Button x:Name="HamburgerMenuButton" Content="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFF6800" Height="39.5" Width="{Binding CompactPaneLength, ElementName=MainSplitView}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationTitle" Text="Início" RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerMenuButton" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="MainSearchTextBox" Width="200" PlaceholderText="Buscar" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.LeftOf="MainSearchButtom"/>
            <Button x:Name="MainSearchButtom" Content="&#xE1A3;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        </RelativePanel>
        <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" CompactPaneLength="46.4" OpenPaneLength="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainSplitViewListView}">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <RelativePanel x:Name="MainSplitRelativPanel">

                    <ListView x:Name="MainSplitViewListView">
                        <ListViewItem x:Name="HomeSplittem" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="HomeStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="HomeIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Text="&#xE80F;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="HomeTextSplitItem" FontSize="22" Text="Início" Margin="11,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="PersonsSplitItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PersonsStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Text="&#xE716;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsTextSplitItem" FontSize="22" Text="Pessoas" Margin="11,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="MediaSplitItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MediaStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MediaIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Text="&#xE958;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MediaTextSplitItem" FontSize="22" Text="Mídias" Margin="11,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="MovementsSplitItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MovementsStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MovementsIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" Text="&#xE7BF;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MovementsTextSplitItem" FontSize="22" Text="Movimentações" Margin="11,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                    </ListView>
                </RelativePanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <Frame x:Name="MainSplitViewFrame" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{x:Null}"/>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

O Designer gera o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso só acontece com o meu código, se eu voltar o código anterior o designer volta a funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em algumas pesquisas que fiz parece ser bug no `VS`

Quando cola o código completo trava:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, adicionando em pequenas partes, o `XAML` funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione tags vazias e em pequenas partes `<Grid>`, etc,
Salve, faça `reload` no `Xaml`
os `ListViewItem` pode copiar o conteúdo completo.

Comment: Verdade, bug grotesco, :-\. Na verdade esse código é parte de um projeto que já estava funcionando quando o designer parou do nada apresentando o erro da imagem. Então para verificar se o problema era com meu código XAML criei um projeto em branco para testar e colei o código lá, mas o erro se repetia.